# Is there a way to determine if a certificate is a EV - Extended Validation cert using node.js?

Tags: node.js, ssl, certificate

Is there a way to determine if a certificate is a EV - Extended Validation cert using node.js ?  I have looked at the results of getPeerCertificate() but don't see/understand how to check if the cert is an EV.